# Load Jenkins config from config.xml

Tags: jenkins

I'm attempting to get my infrastucture defined as code. To do this I've spun up 2 jenkins servers with puppet. I then manually configured one, and copied the working config.xml to the other.

Since jenkins has the ability to read in the config.xml file, I would expect the second jenkins server to be an identical twin of the first.

Unfortunatly the second jenkins server crashes at startup with the following error:

```
Manager password must not be empty or null.
```

**Things I've tried:**

- do a recursive grep of the /var/lib/jenkins directory looking for any string that matches 'managerPassword' (found 0)
- copy the secrets files and directories from the old to the new one.

**About:**

Jenkins 1.572
Ldap plugin 1.10.2

I'm sure there is a way to copy the config from one jenkins server to another.
Has anyone done it? 
What files am I missing?

**Full Error:**

`hudson.util.HudsonFailedToLoad: org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'initialDirContextFactory': Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'managerPassword' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Manager password must not be empty or null.
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:234)
Caused by: org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'initialDirContextFactory': Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'managerPassword' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Manager password must not be empty or null.
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.execute(Reactor.java:269)
    at jenkins.InitReactorRunner.run(InitReactorRunner.java:44)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.executeReactor(Jenkins.java:896)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.<init>(Jenkins.java:795)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:82)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:78)
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:222)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'initialDirContextFactory': Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'managerPassword' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Manager password must not be empty or null.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1279)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1010)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at`

**Update**

I tried recursivly (and while preserving permissions) copying the entire /var/lib/jenkins directory from the primary server to the secondary and restarted. It gives the same error about 'managerPassword'

Answer (score 1):

I had the same exact error very recently.  I realized after setting security to false in config.xml and manually setting up ldap on the new host that I forgot to import the certificate to the java keystore as we are using ldaps.  Here are the steps I took to resolve the problem.  For reference, I'm using java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.65, jenkins v1.568 on Centos 6.5 fully updated.

Stop Jenkins

```
service jenkins stop
```

Sync Jenkins home dir (used -I flag to overwrite existing files):

```
rsync -avI user@old_host:/var/lib/jenkins/* /var/lib/jenkins/
```

Backup cacerts on the new host:

```
cp /etc/pki/java/cacerts /some/backup/dir
```

Copy cacerts from old host to new (or import via keytool if you have other certs on that new host you need to keep):

```
scp user@old_host:/etc/pki/java/cacerts /etc/pki/java/cacerts
```

(import method: keytool -import -alias "some-name-for-cert" -keystore cacerts -trustcacerts -file "/path/to/cert.crt")

Start Jenkins

```
service jenkins start
```

Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to comment and recommend importing a cert so please don't be harsh if this doesn't fix it.  I signed up here when I came across your error.  Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

it's a random problem accured also to me..you can open config.xml file in a root directory of Jenkins and turn false useSecurity tag. now you have resetted security management